# How to print the output of a text file in table format with in line columns

Tags: text-processing

my output file contains a below

output.txt

```
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|FSNAME:|AVAILABLE:|AVAILABILITY
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|/opt:|yes:|1.4GB
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|/data:|yes:|30GB
```

The above values are added to `output.txt` from there respective variables, so the size of the output varies and I am unable to put a limit on letters.

*I don't have `column` or `miller` commands installed!*

I used below methods but the output not in order

- `awk '{ gsub(":", " " ) } 1' output.txt`

  ```
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |FSNAME |AVAILABLE |AVAILABILITY
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/opt |yes |1.4GB
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/data |yes |30GB
  ```
- `awk -F ':' '{printf "%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' output.txt`

  ```
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |FSNAME    |AVAILABLE|AVAILABILITY
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/opt      |yes      |1.4GB
  2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/data     |yes      |30GB
  ```

If one of the variable size written to my output file more then 10s then the format is not comming good as below

output.txt

```
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|FSNAME:|AVAILABLE:|AVAILABILITY
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|/opt:|yessssssss:|1.4GB
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - :|/data:|yes:|30GB
```

```
awk -F ':' '{printf "%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' output.txt
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |FSNAME    |AVAILABLE|AVAILABILITY
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/opt      |yessssssss|1.4GB
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO -  |/data     |yes      |30GB
```

Please help with a solution?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it is unclear what the _desired_ output looks like, or what is currently wrong with the output examples you showed (apart from unequal column sizes). Please edit your post to include an example of desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following double-pass approach should format the fields to fixed column width:

```
awk -F':\\|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (length($i)>max[i]) max[i]=length($i);} next;}
           {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=sprintf("%-*s",max[i],$i)}1' output.txt output.txt
```

This will process `output.txt` *twice* (hence you have to specify it twice as argument to `awk`).

- In the first pass (where `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, is equal to `NR`, the global line counter), we simply look for the maximum length of each field entry (by iterating over all fields from `$1` to `$NF`), and store it in an array `max`.
- In the second pass, we (re-)format the fields via `sprintf` to a fixed width as determined from the `max` array of maximum field widths.
- The field separator for input will be taken as the combined `:|` character sequence (with proper escaping, since multi-character *input* field separators are treated as regular expressions, and `|` has a special meaning there). The output field separator will be set to a single `|`.

Result for your example

```
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - |FSNAME|AVAILABLE|AVAILABILITY
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - |/opt  |yes      |1.4GB       
2020.11.07-22.3.31 INFO - |/data |yes      |30GB
```

Comment: Super, thanks for your quick response. Its working.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Please note that I would still ask you to edit the information I asked about in the [other comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622849/how-to-print-the-output-of-a-text-file-in-table-format-with-in-line-columns/622851?noredirect=1#comment1165120_622849) into your question, so that future readers arriving here with a similar problem can understand the context of question and solution more easily.